# Does Markdown not recognize &ndashes in comments?

Tags: support, comments, markdown

Is this a bug to the comments?  What other HTML entities does it also not recognize?

Comment: &ndash; &mdash; &nbsp;

Comment: @JeremyBanks unless i have character map open or memorize the alt-#s, i'm stuck, in other words?

Comment: I guess so, though in general I've found a text file with the specific characters I use frequently to be more friendly than stuff like Character Map. On OS X in specific, I can you press Alt-Minus and Alt-Shift-Minus for the dashes, and Alt-Space for the non-breaking space. I don't know if Windows has similar shortcuts.

Comment: @erich I don't know what platform you're on, but on mine (Ubuntu, but anything with X Windows will be able to do it), it's [Compose] [-] [-] [.] → `&ndash;` / [Compose] [-] [-] [-] → `&mdash;` / [Compose] [Space] [Space] → `&nbsp;` ... most compositions are fairly intuitive, and other common ones are easy to remember.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus i'm used to such autocorrects in microsoft word, but not in general on the web.  mathjax is enabled in comments however; what is the equivalent symbol there?

Comment: @erich Mathjax I don't know - I was talking about using the [compose key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) for keyboard input on [X Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) (which would have been clearer if `<kbd>` worked in comments).

Comment: [WinCompose](https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose) seems to offer compose key functionality for MS Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments to not support any HTML (including entities), but rather rely on a subset of Markdown commonly referred to as "[mini Markdown](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/)."

[How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [New, Improved Comments with @reply](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/) may be useful reads.