# Does Mathjax not support certain commands in comments?

Tags: support, comments, mathjax

In [trying to get an en-dash to appear in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252052/281446), I discovered Mathjax is not a viable alternative either.  How come I can't use `\textendash` in comments?  (Also: `\textemdash`.)  Are there any other commands that don't work either?

Comment: Pasting in  – from the post below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of MathJax commands [is here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands). It does not include `\textendash` (and many other LaTeX commands that are text-oriented as opposed to formula-oriented).

Also, most SE sites, including this one, do not have MathJax enabled at all. See [Which Stack Exchange sites use MathJax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax)

The only way  to obtain en-dash in a comment is to paste it in from somewhere else, or to type it directly on your keyboard (if you remember the key combination). In posts you can use HTML `&ndash;` to get –.