# Relax the spam prevention filter to allow blocked characters in @-replies

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, spam, display-names, comment-replies

I understand the [change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266440/unihan-characters-in-comments) made to filter certain Unicode characters due to a large influx of spam. But, is it possible for the validation to allow exceptions for usernames containing Asian characters when `@`-replying to a comment?

On [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), I tried to reply to a comment from someone with a username comprised of three Unicode characters, [오준수](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/21814/%EC%98%A4%EC%A4%80%EC%88%98), but it was denied with a "Comments cannot contain that content" error.  I selected the name using the tab autocompleter, which these [two](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2780) [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168155/259381) seem to suggest should work.

> [image]

I found this other [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263416/comments-cannot-contain-users-name), but the answer was to use only the Latin characters in the name.  The user I was trying to ping has no Latin characters in his username though.

Another [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261609/259381) that seems to be very similar has a workaround for characters in the body of questions or answers, but I don't think this would work for pinging users in comments though.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't think this is an issue with the username, but the content that the comment has itself. It could be that the words "this is" and "test" are likely some spam-related barrier, and the length and that combination is what blocks the comment, not the username you are trying to reply to itself.

Comment: @오준수 Hi there. I'm wondering to see if this comment is ever going to get through, and if it will ever be published on Stack Exchange. Well, it works here, so this seems to be unique to ELL (and other possible sites). Just for some background, Stack Exchange has been getting waves of chinese spam that doesn't stop, which explains why chinese characters are blocked. That's likely the reason.

Comment: Changed to feature request and reopened, but not sure if it's technically possible to do what you ask for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have been working on designing a smarter filter (specifically, [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha) has), but we'd only deployed it on Travel.SE at this point.

We've now expanded it to other sites that had the simpler "is there a Chinese character in this post" filter in place (which includes ELL.SE).

The smarter filter should let you make your comment! Let us know if not.

Comment: Does it mean the filter does not block comments at all?

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, the filter still applies to comments.

Comment: It worked for me on ELL.  Thank you

Comment: Is the smarter filter on Super User? https://i.imgur.com/WKXAEUM.png